# How to use certificates in Java 11 with RestTemplate and Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

An agency has sent me several files to consume their API: **cert.pem**, **key-u.pem**, **CompanyRootCA.pem** and **SDFGSSDF_1.p12**.

**cert.pem**:

```
----- BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY -----
... 1234 ...
----- END RSA PRIVATE KEY -----
----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----
... abcdef ...
----- END CERTIFICATE -----
```

**key-u.pem**:

```
----- BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY -----
... 1234 ...
----- END RSA PRIVATE KEY -----
```

*Note that the key for key-u.pem is the same in cert.pem.*

**CompanyRootCA.pem**:

```
----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----
... G h I J K ...
----- END CERTIFICATE -----
```

and the file **SDFGSSDF_1.p12** I can't open with a text editor.

I run the following command in the linux terminal and it works for me successfully:
`curl -vvv --key ./key-u.pem --cert ./cert.pem --cacert ./CompanyRootCA.pem -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"parameters" : {}}' https://some.url.com.ar/api/2.1/server.php`.

Also as a test run sending only the cert.pem and it also works for me:
`curl -vvv --cert ./cert.pem -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"parameters" : {}}' https://some.url.com.ar/api/2.1/server.php`.

Now, how can I use these certificates and keys to be able to send requests to the API? I am using Java Open JDK 11 with Spring Boot and RestTemplate.

Comment: They are crazy. They should not have sent you their private key in a million years. They have just broken their own PKI security. Now they will have to rekey all their certificates, whcih means generating a new keypair and obtaining new certificates. If they are sending you a private key for *your* use, that is also crazy: it isn't private if they know it; you should generate your own. Something is seriously wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a Spring boot app to use SSL you need to update your app configuration to include something like this.

```
server:
  port: 8080
  SSL:
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: classpath:keystore/testkeystore.p12
    key-store-password: password
```

In the above example, this p12 is located in the src/main/resources directory

And you will need to add some rest template configuration to use them in API requests downstream.

Here is a good Baeldung article on using SSL in Spring Boot:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate